# Call Unsubscribe on conditional basis in angular 4

Tags: angular

We are not using routing in our angular 4 application. Because of lack of routes I can not use `ngDestroy()` effectively and unsubscribe from the subscription for hidden components. How could I do that? Is it possible?

```
if(componentIsVisible==true){
subscribe...
}

else {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
      }
```

Comment: can you provide more info on the same  ?

Comment: Yes Rahul, Hope it is more clear now!

Comment: you can assign  the subscription to a variable an then where ever you need to unsubscribe just call `<variable>.unsubscribe()`

Comment: How can I subscribe again? Because I am able to unsubscribe but can not subscribe again

Comment: i am guessing you will `unsubscribe` when you leave the component , and on ngOnInit you can again subscribe back when you renter the component

Comment: The problem is I am just hiding the component using *ngIf. So ngOnInit runs only once.

Comment: so you  can set a varaible in ngIf which when turned to true or false you can call a method and in that you can subscribe or unsubcribe ?

Comment: How can I subscribe a variable if once Unsubscribed it?

Comment: you will have some parent component right you set that to tryue and false and depending upon that subscribe and unsubscribe